# Is there an implementation of the minP or Westfall & Young corrections?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

Let us consider variables $X_1,\dots,X_k$. They are highly dependent.
We want to perform some test for any pair $(X_i,Y)$ and imply proper multiple-comparisons correction.

As i understand, Westfall & Young or minP/maxT corrections should be efficient in this task. But i can't find any general implementation in R. And code it from scratch is hard and dangerous, as for me.

Is there any implementation of this methods or any alternatives?

*Edit 1:* Practical example.

```
X1=c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1)
X2=c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0)
X3=c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1)`
set.seed(16)
Y=rnorm(8,mean = 3)*X1+rnorm(8)

p_1=wilcox.test(Y[X1==0],Y[X1==1])$p.value
p_2=wilcox.test(Y[X2==0],Y[X2==1])$p.value
p_3=wilcox.test(Y[X3==0],Y[X3==1])$p.value

p_vec=c(p_1,p_2,p_3)

p.adjust(p_vec,method = "holm")
```

Holm's correction is too strict for such dependent tests.
I wanted to permute Y and perform Westfall & Young correction.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on which hypotheses you're actually trying to test given your data. Do you have multiple observations for each variable $X_i$ and $Y$? More generally, the R library `multtest` provides methods for adjusting p-values using the step-down maxT and minP procedures of Westfall & Young. Have you already taken a look at `multtest`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers, I have, say, N patients with $X_1, \dots,X_k$ and $Y$ measured for every patient.
As i understood, multtest can only be used if $X_i$ is continuous and $Y$ is binary.
In my case $X_i$ is binary, $Y$ is continuous and i want to perform Wilcoxon test with resampling of $Y$ ranks. Also im interested in case when $Y$ is binary and we use Exact Fisher's test.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused about your data. I assume you have multiple measurements for every variable $X_i$ for every patient? Otherwise I'm not clear on how you'd like to *"perform some test for any pair $(X_i, Y)$"*. Perhaps it might help if you were to provide some sample data and code (since this post has an `r` code tag) that shows what test(s) you'd like to perform on which (subset of) your data. I'm also wondering whether modelling `Y` directly as a function of the `X_i`s wouldn't be more sensible. This might avoid the whole multiple comparison issue altogether.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I apologize for such unclear data. I meant pairs of random variables $(X_i,Y),\quad i=1\dots k$ .
I added a code example to the post.

Comment: I'm very confused about your data and what you're trying to do; in your post you state that you want to perform pairwise tests (Wilcoxon rank tests in your case) of random variables $(X_i, Y)$ where $X_i$ is binary and $Y$ is continuous; but in your code you perform tests on disjoint subsets of $Y$.

Comment: Good day, @MauritsEvers! Isn't that three implementations of Wilcoxon test? Let us addume we want to test pair, $(X_1,Y)$. We define _$H_0$: there is no shift between densities f(Y|X==0) and f(Y|X==1)._ We divide $Y$ into two subsamples, corresponding to $X_1=0$ and $X_1=1$ and perform WMW test on them. That's what i did in my code.

Comment: Hi Kess. Yes you've got three Wilcoxon tests; but you're clearly not testing pairs $(X_i, Y)$; you're testing sets of disjoint observations for $Y$ (as you yourself demonstrate in your last comment). So that's very different from what you state in your original post and earlier comments (*"We want to perform some test for any pair $(X_i,Y)$"*. Since $Y$ is continuous, why not do simple $t$-tests, or -- better still -- model $Y$ as a function of $X_i$ which avoids the whole multiple testing business all together?

Comment: Good day, @MauritsEvers! Sorry, but I still dont understad, where I am wrong. L test two random variables $A,B$ with WMW test on $N$-size sample.So, I need to compare subsamples  $B_l$ and $B_m$, where $\forall i \in l => A_i=0 $, $ \forall j \in m => A_j=1$ and $|l|+|m|=N$. In current problem I have not single $A$, but a group of random variables $X_i, i=1\dots k$ and I need to test them simultaneously. In my task i can't assume neither normality of continous variable, nor big sample size. So Im using not t-test but WMW test. Also, the design of the research doesnt let me model $Y$ from $X_i$

Comment: Hi Kess. I think we may be misunderstanding each other; I don't know how else I can say what I already said without repeating myself. As you mentioned in one of your previous comments you'd like to characterise the *"shift between densities f(Y|X==0) and f(Y|X==1)"*; so you're pairwise tests involve the conditional $Y$s only; you don't test $(X_1, Y)$. Provided your sample data is representative I don't see how *"the design [...] doesn't let me model $Y$ from $X_i$"*. It does. Anyway, lest we go around in circles, here's hoping somebody else can help you.